# Hive equivalent to for getting data from current partition date

Tags: hive

I have been trying to automate a report in Hive which requires the data to be taken for the last 30 days.

Equivalent in SQL:

```
select * from som_table where part >=  Sysdate-30 and part < sysdate-1
```

I am using the below query but I am not able to get the MR jobs started.

```
select *
from some_table
where part >= date_add(date_add(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),-1),1 - day(date_add(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),-1)))
and part < date_add(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),-1)
```

I searched but it says that I have to find a solution through scripting, but I need to run this query in another job.

Comment: "I searched but it says that I have to find a solution through scripting, but I need to run this query in another job."  Please explain what that means? What is the specific error you are seeing?

Comment: I simply cannot understand why you translate "SysDate -30" into a very complicated formula that finally produces "SysDate -day(SysDate)". And anyway "SysDate -30" is Oracle dialect, not standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think your formulae in the Hive version are more complicated that they need to be. Try the following:

```
Select
Date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), 30) as thirty_days_ago,
Date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), 1) as one_day_ago
```

Comment: Sub(-1) = Add(+1) i.e. "tomorrow", not "yesterday"  ;-)